# python identity for global variables

Tags: python, global, identity

```
def func():
      global x
      print 'x is', x
      x = 2
      print id(x)
      print 'Changed global x to', x

x = 50
print id(x)
func()
print 'Value of x is', x
print id(x)
```

**output**

```
32308172
x is 50
32308748
Changed global x to 2
Value of x is 2
32308748
```

I am expecting `id()` should return same value for all the three times because same copy of `x` is used by all globally. Why is it behaving like this.

Comment: Integers are immutable, and `global` refers to the **name** `x`, not whatever underlying object it happens to be assigned to. Look at e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: it's the ID of the object, not of the variable. try: `a = 1` `id(a)` `b = 1` `id(b)`

Comment: @Roberto in CPython, that example might give confusing results, as small integers are *interned*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh, sorry. Thanks for the heads up, that's interesting! Should I delete the comment, or leave it as it is with your underlying comment?

Comment: Some one can you please explain the above code diagramatically same as C pointers. I am from C background. I will be very thankful if above code will be explained using a diagram.

Answer (score 3):

"Variables" in Python are just labels you attach to objects.  The function `id()` returns the id of the object you pass to it, not the id of a "variable".  If you point a name to a different object, you will get a different id.

Comment: Sorry I am not understanding. What I am thinking is if we use "global" keyword, by seeing that name no other memory location will be created, same memory location of x(defined outside of function), should be used. Assuming that id() returns memory location.

Comment: @user1423015:  No, a name does not refer to a memory location in Python, regardless of global or not.  A name is just a label that can be attached to aribtrary objects.  You can attach multiple names to the same object without any problem.  The global keyword declares that some name is to be *scoped* globally, which is completely unrelated to memory locations.  It just means that if you reassign that name, the global name will be attached to a different object, instead of creating a new local name.

Answer (score 0):

They are referring to different objects ("small integers"). See http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/ for example.

Since integers are immutable, the (global) name `x` refers to different memory locations if the value of the variable is changed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of changing the value of x is because of that you define x as `global` in your function so python threat with x as a global variable in the scope of module , and also the `id` of your object will be changed as integers are immutable and after assigning python create a new address for your object.

if you dont use function you will see the same result :

```
>>> x=2
>>> id(x)
33263936
>>> x=4
>>> id(x)
33263888
```